# What is the difference between giaddr field in DHCP response and DHCP option 3?

Tags: dhcp

I have a DHCP client that I've used for years.  Until now, it has always gotten its gateway IP address from DHCP Option #3. Now running with a new DHCP server that does not provide option 3 (yes I know its an option), so is the client supposed to use the giaddr field of the DHCP response?
The RFCs talk about giaddr being a relay agent, but other places I read says it can be the gateway IP.
What is the difference between the two fields?

Answer (score 1):

The difference between giaddr and option 3 is that giaddr is read by the DHCP server and defines to what IP address the DHCP server sends the response to. Option 3 defines what is transmitted within the response as the gateway (router) address from server to client.

If you change the DHCP server and that new server does not send the option 3, then I‘m sure it‘s a matter of configuration. It would be a very strange DHCP server that does not support sending the gateway IP address, when configured.

Comment: thanks for responding...Are you saying that the giaddr field would be populated by the client at the time of the request?

Comment: Reviewing RFC2131, section 4.1 says that the client populates the giaddr field with zero if the client and server are on the same subnet; but how does the client even know if they are?  I'm just getting more confused...

Comment: The giaddr field is actually populated by a relay agent. Due to the use of broadcasts, the DHCP protocol is limited to one subnet. Relay agents overcome this limitation by acting as a server towards the client and acting as a client toward the server. The DHCP server only needs to send the answer according to the giaddr field to make the relay agent work. To check the subnet: A client simply compares the IP address of the server (where the response came from) with the assigned IP address.

Comment: Since the client initially has no idea where the server is, does that mean that if the client sees the giaddr field populated in the response, then a relay agent was invovled in the transaction?  Further... as you said, the location of the DHCP server (on or off subnet) can also be derived from the netmask and IP address of the server...   Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes. But it is not guaranteed, that the response includes the giaddr in packets coming from the relay agent. Giaddr really only has a meaning on the way to and not from the server.

Comment: So, is it correct to say that the client really doesn't even need to know that a relay agent is used?

Comment: Yes, that‘s the whole idea of relay agents. And therefore your original question “… is the client supposed to use the giaddr field of the DHCP response?“ is answered: No. For several reasons. Giaddr only has relevance in the packets from relay agent to server and the client should not care about it.

Comment: Great discussion... thanks for the answers!